# How to listen to button action add combobox and listen to action again Java

Tags: java, combobox

My question is this: I want have a frame with a combo box and a ok button.  I want to select a item from that list and click ok and based on the selected item have a new combo box with new items.

```
String[] locals = {"a bunch of strings"};

JComboBox<String> localsList = new JComboBox<String>(locals);
        localsList.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        p.add(localsList);
        p.add(okButton);

        okButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String value = localsList.getSelectedItem().toString();

                switch(value){

                    case("a bunch of strings"):
                        JComboBox<String> concelhosList = new JComboBox<String>(concelhosL);
                        concelhosList.setSelectedIndex(0);
                        p.add(concelhosList);

                }
            }
        });


        okButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String value = concelhosList.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }
        });
```

The problem is that the `concelhosList` variable stays within the first action listner and so the second action listner doesn't recognize it, and eclipse says I need to create the variable.

How do I fix this or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

make it a member variable which you only then initialize in the actionPerformed. also you don't need 2 action listener. just use if-statement to check if `concelhosList` is null. if yes you ignore it and go for the other one.

code could look like this:

```
okButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(concelhosList==null){
            String value = localsList.getSelectedItem().toString();

            switch(value){

                case("a bunch of strings"):
                    concelhosList = new JComboBox<String>(concelhosL);
                    concelhosList.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    p.add(concelhosList);

            }
            }else{
                String value = concelhosList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it says at `concelhosList = new JComboBox<String>(concelhosL);` that `Local variable concelhosList defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

Comment: concelhosL doesn't even exist in the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

If you need your `JComboBox` in other logics you write - just extract it to an upper-more scope.

In your example, I would suggest putting it next to the first line, like so:

```
private String[] locals = {"a bunch of strings"};
private JComboBox<String> concelhosList;
```

Comment: its set and not get therefore that is just fine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer got that - but stills seems strange. I this resetting the user's pick? Seems strange a-bit.. but I edited it out...

Comment: that just sets the item you see first when you start initialize the GUI. i don't think there is any need to set it to 0 as i think its standard. but if you want it so display an empty item first you set it to -1 for example